# How can I store variables in one file to use them in the whole cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question concerning Kubernetes. Could you please advice if we can keep some variables in one yaml file and use them in each pod of the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use kubernetes [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) where you can store the variables and attach the same to pod.  For more details you can refer kubernetes documentation.  Below is sample of config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-12-27T18:36:28Z
  name: game-config-env-file
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "809965"
  uid: d9d1ca5b-eb34-11e7-887b-42010a8002b8
data:
  allowed: '"true"'
  enemies: aliens
  lives: "3"
```